# Finding element on index position of a list which has same elements

Tags: python

Here loopid1 becomes 1 and when the it's index is found out everytime it gives 0 as the list is made of 1. What I want to do is after every iteration it gives the index value as 0, 1, 2 but everytime I get 0,0,0.

```
LoopIdlist = [1, 4,8] 
BendLoopId1List = [1, 1, 1]
indexoffacel = -1
bendcounter = -1 
for bendata in BendList:
    bendcounter = bendcounter+1
    loopid1=BendLoopIdiList[bendcounter]
    print("loopidl: + str(loopid1))
    if(loopidi in LoopIdlist):
        indexoffacel = LoopIdlist.index(loopidl)
        print("indexoffacel: " + str(indexoffacel))
```

Comment: What is `BendList` in your code?

Comment: Sorry my bad. BendList =[1,2,3]

Comment: loopid1 is going to be always 1, since your BendLoopId1List is having [1,1,1] only

Answer (score 0):

The list `index` method always gives the first found position. An easy trick to solve this can be: `reversed(LoopIdlist).index(what_you_are_looking_for)`